# How to Fetch User Selection in Drop Down Selection in Odoo Website Module

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo

I created a drop down menu inside odoo website module's checkout page (/shop/cart, code shown below), how can I fetch the user's selection and save it to a field inside my model? Current using latest version of Odoo 16.

XML:

```
<xpath expr="//td[hasclass('td-qty')]" position="after">
    <td class="text-center td-something" name="something">
        <select class="some1" name="some1" id="some123">
            <t t-if="request.website.sale_get_order().website_order_line.some_field">
                <option selected="true" t-value="request.website.sale_get_order().website_order_line.some_field" t-esc="request.website.sale_get_order().website_order_line.some_field"/>
            </t>
            <t t-else="">
                <option value="" selected="true">-</option>
            </t>
            <t t-foreach="request.env['res.partner'].sudo().search([])" t-as="x">
                <t t-foreach="x.some_field2" t-as="y">
                    <t t-if="y.name">
                        <t t-if="(request.env.user.partner_id.member_id in y.name)">
                            <t t-set="current_order_line" t-value="y.some_one2many.product_id" class="temp"/>
                            <!-- The line above takes the product ID of current product -->
                            <option t-value="y.id" t-esc="y.name"/>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </select>
    </td>
</xpath>
```

My attempt on JS:

```
$('#alloc_alloc').on('change', 'select.alloc', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $( ".alloc" ).val();
    var ID= $( ".temp" ).val();
});
```

My attempt on controller (inherited cart_update_json method in WebsiteSale class):

```
value = kw.get('value')
current_line = kw.get('ID')
record = request.env['sale.order.line'].sudo().search([('product_id', '=', current_line)])
if record:
    record.write({'some_field': value})
else:
    print("Test")
```

Is it possible to do this without JS? I am not that familiar with JS.